# What is the syntax for if false in nVelocity?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, velocity, nvelocity

What is the syntax for an not true or false if statement in nVelocity (or Velocity)?

And more importantly, where is this in the nVelocity docs? I've been Googling for quite a while to no avail.

I've tried several different combinations such as:

```
#if (!$artist.IsFestival)

$artist.FestivalName

#end
```

and

```
#if ($artist.IsFestival == false)

$artist.FestivalName

#end
```

So frustrating!

Thanks in advance!

-Ev

Comment: nvelocity docs: http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html

Comment: is IsFestival a public property?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer your link to nvelocity doc doesn't work anymore... because of velocity syntax error! lol

Comment: @BritishDeveloper nope, it's because the website switched to a PHP-based CMS. Here's the NVelocity documentation: http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.NVelocity.ashx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these should have worked, so I think you may have a problem accessing "isFestival". You should try the bean syntax `$artist.festival` or the method syntax `$artist.isFestival()` (you are now using a mix of both).
The method returns a boolean, right?

For debugging try to just print out the result to see if it works:

```
 $artist            ## see if the artist is defined
 $artist.IsFestival  ## maybe an error   
 $artist.festival    ## should be true or false
 $artist.isFestival() ## should be true or false
```

Update: Just read that you are asking about nVelocity. It is possible that my answer only applies to the Java version. Give it a try anyway.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot.

But I what I really need to know if how to negate the test, so the if something is _not_ true. How do I say: if (NOT $artist.IsFestival)?

Comment: Both of the patterns you showed should work (`!$x` and `$x == false`).

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll check to make sure the property is set to the right value